# Filter error messages in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a multi-page (html templates) form which I am validating using Angular. Is it possible to display only certain error messages using $setValidity and ng-repeat using a string filter?  If not, any suggestions?

I want to catch errors, $setValidity and then conditionally display certain error messages based on the page of the form the error was from.

Here is the Angular validation code:

```
 ///TEAM DATA
    if (!$scope.formData.TeamContactFirstName) {
            $scope.signupform.$setValidity('TEAM: Please provide a Team Contact First Name', false)
            $scope.failedForms.team = true;
            isValid = false;
        }
        if (!$scope.formData.TeamContactLastName) {
            $scope.signupform.$setValidity('TEAM: Please provide a Team Contact Last Name', false)
            $scope.failedForms.team = true;
            isValid = false;
        }
//PROJECT BASICS
       if (!$scope.formData.Title) {
            $scope.signupform.$setValidity('BASICS: Please provide a project title.', false)
            $scope.failedForms.basics = true;
            isValid = false;
        }
if (!$scope.formData.ProjectLocation) {
        $scope.signupform.$setValidity('BASICS: Please provide the location of the project', false)
        $scope.failedForms.basics = true;
        isValid = false;
    }
```

Here is the repeater:

```
<div ng-show="signupform.$invalid" class="alert-box alert radius">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key, errors) in signupform.$error">

            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="e in errors"><strong>{{ key }}</strong>.</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to be able to only display the TEAM DATA errors with this repeater.  Filter?

Comment: I am not sure what is inside $error, but I think angular ng-repeat skip items start with `$` in key.

Comment: Thanks.  There is nothing wrong with the code though- it is working.  The question is if is it possible to add a filter to conditionally show results.  If not, perhaps another alternative.

Comment: sorry, looks like I misunderstood your question, hope someone could answer.

Comment: e in errors | filter:'TEAM' doesnt work?

Comment: @Petr  No.  That was my first go to.  I was thinking it would pick up a keyword in a string as well.  No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite strange use of `$setValidity`, but anyways:

```
<div ng-show="signupform.$invalid" class="alert-box alert radius">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key, errors) in signupform.$error">

            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="e in errors" ng-if="key.indexOf('TEAM:') == 0"><strong>{{ key }}</strong>.</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```